# Which docker images were pulled from Azure container registry by Azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-log-analytics, azure-container-registry, azure-log-analytics-workspace

For cleaning up space in our Azure Container Registry I want to know which Docker images were pulled the last time and in addition how often they have been pulled for a given amount of time.

The images that are being pulled from an Azure pipeline are refrenced using a versions string like tag: e.g. 2.3.0 and not using the sha256:... string.

I have found some posts on Stackoverflow pointing me to the ACR log analystics workspace "ContainerRegistryRepositoryEvents" table based information that can be queried using Kusto query language.

There I could define queries to get me the amount of Docker images being pulled but the given results do not make sense to me.

One such query is

```
  ContainerRegistryRepositoryEvents
  | where OperationName == "Pull"
  | where TimeGenerated > ago(180d)
  | summarize PullsFromIP=count() by Repository, CallerIpAddress, Digest, Tag
  | project Repository, CallerIpAddress, PullsFromIP, Digest, Tag
  | sort by PullsFromIP, Repository, CallerIpAddress
```

The results show me that most of pulled Docker images (=entries in the ContainerRegistryRepositoryEvents table) do not have a version-string like Tag (e.g. 2.3.0) but instead it is sha256:asdasd. Also I can see that the Docker image with tag 2.3.0 has the same Digest than another Docker image that has a sha256:... based Tag (here the Tag is the same like the Digest).

I would have expected that the docker image with the 2.3.0 tag would have been downloaded many times but actually the Docker image with the sha256:... string (pointing to the same Docker image like tag 2.3.0) was pulled most of the time.

Can somebody explain why I see these results and how I could maybe write a fancy Kusto query to see for every Docker image that has a x.y.z based Tag how often it was pulled (considering the fact that there are other entries with different Tag content but the same Digest content)?

Can I maybe write some fancy Kusto query for combining the amount of pulls for the sha256:... based Tag entries with the entries with the human readable Tag strings (e.g. the 2.3.0) so that I can finally see that e.g. all Docker images with the tag 2.3.0

I know this is a complicated topic/question and I appreciate all support.

Thank you